# Image not showing in window, Image.Source seems to be valid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am working on a WPF project. I need to display an image when the new window opens, but I don't seem to get it to work. I feel like I've tried everything.

```xml
<Window x:Class="iTool.ProfileWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:iTool"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="iTool: User Profile" Height="800" Width="1200" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="User Profile" FontSize="30" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <StackPanel Width="300" Height="700">
                    <Image x:Name="imgUserProfile" Height="200" Width="200" Margin="50"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txbFirstName"/>
                    <TextBlock x:Name="txbLastName"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```cs
    public partial class ProfileWindow : Window
    {
        public ProfileWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            imgUserProfile.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(MainWindow.activeUserImage, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        }
    }
```

In Debug watch:
activeUserImage = "images/samson_profile.jpg"

imgUserProfile.Source = {pack://application:,,,/iTool;component/images/samson_profile.jpg}

The image exists in the "images" folder, but is not added to the project as existing file.

When the ProfileWindow opens all I can see is User Profile label, no image.

Comment: Make sure the image file's Build Action is set to Resource.

Comment: The image file is not included into project as an existing file. The folder is included, but not the image file. Is it possible to get it to work without the inclusion of the image file into the project?

Comment: Assuming that `images/samson_profile.jpg` is a valid relative path, `new BitmapImage(new Uri(MainWindow.activeUserImage, UriKind.Relative)` should work.

Comment: That is why I am so confused. It does not work with either `UriKind.Relative` or `Urikind.RelativeOrAbsolute`. If i input `Source="images/samson_profile.jpg"` straight into XAML it works fine.